# Undeclared identifier error in if and else if (C++)

Tags: if-statement

Why do I have a "Q undeclared identifier" error in my code?

```
if(comboBox1->Text == "bbl/D (BPD)")
{
    double Q = nQ;
}
else if (comboBox1->Text == "scf/D (SCFPD)")
{
    double Q = nQ * 11;
}
else if(comboBox1->Text == "m^3/D (CUMPD)")
{
    double Q = nQ * 11;
```

Comment: Please specify the language you are using by adding the proper tags.

Comment: Looks like C. In the sample, each branch defines their own `Q` variable that lasts as long as the if statement block. Move the declaration of `Q` (`double Q;`) above the `if` chain. Also use `strcmp` instead of `comboBox1->Text=="bbl/D (BPD)"`, which doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

Putting on my psychic debugging hat [ which I purchased cheap from Raymond Chen :-) ], it's almost certainly later in the code that that when you actually attempt to *use* `Q`.

Declaring `Q` within a block like:

```
{
    double Q = 42.0;
}
```

in most C-like languages will see it going out of scope at the closing brace, meaning you won't be able to use it later.

If you *do* want to use it later, declare it *before* the `if` sequence and just *assign* to it within the blocks, something like:

```
double Q = 0.0;
if(comboBox1->Text=="bbl/D (BPD)") {
    Q = nQ;
} else if(comboBox1->Text=="scf/D (SCFPD)") {
    Q = nQ * 11;
} else if(comboBox1->Text=="m^3/D (CUMPD)") {
    Q = nQ * 11;
}
// Now you can use Q.
```

Also be aware that, if your language is C (you haven't actually specified it in the current question), comparing strings should be done with the `strcmp` family, *not* `==`. As in:

```
if (strcmp (comboBox1->Text, "bbl/D (BPD)") == 0)
```

If you find with the code I've given you that `Q` is not changing from its initial value, that's the most likely reason.

Comment: Q don't change in the if chain, when i do it! at the end of chain it will be zero.

Comment: @mojtaba, if Q is not changing then none of the conditions are being met. If that's C, it's because you're using `==` rather than `strcmp`. Updating answer.

Comment: i check it by break points. when if constrain is true if body will run but Q won't change. as you suggest i will check it by strcmp.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your entire code. But you are limiting the question's scope to each `if` block. Declare your variable outside the `if` conditions:

```
double Q;
if (comboBox1->Text == "bbl/D (BPD)")
{
    Q = nQ;
}
else if (comboBox1->Text == "scf/D (SCFPD)")
{
    Q = nQ * 11;
}
else if (comboBox1->Text == "m^3/D (CUMPD)")
{
    Q = nQ * 11;
```

Comment: Q don't change in the if chain, when i do it! at the end of chain it will be zero.